# Remove checkboxes in customer-account-edit and show all info

Tags: magento2, javascript, customer-account, knockoutjs

In customer-account-edit page magento decided (why???) to insert 2 checkboxes:
[image]

By default only if you click on those checkboxes the other fields appear so you can change them.

I would like to remove this functionality and to show all fields from page load.

Simply display block will not work as magento2 does some knockoutjs and disables the fields but I cannot find where it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Found out you have to change: `app/design/frontend/package/theme/Magento_Customer/web/change-email-password.js` and remove the else line in this function:

```
/**
         * Check choice
         * @private
         */
        _checkChoice: function () {
            if ($(this.options.changeEmailSelector).is(':checked') &&
                $(this.options.changePasswordSelector).is(':checked')) {
                this._showAll();
            } else if ($(this.options.changeEmailSelector).is(':checked')) {
                this._showEmail();
            } else if ($(this.options.changePasswordSelector).is(':checked')) {
                this._showPassword();
            } else {
                //this._hideAll();
            }
        },
```